# What is the difference between this two SQL queries?

Tags: mysql

**This query is giving wrong answer**

First query:

```sql
SELECT h.hacker_id,
       h.name,
       COUNT(c.challenge_id)
FROM hackers h
     INNER JOIN challenges c ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
GROUP BY h.hacker_id,
         h.name
HAVING COUNT(c.challenge_id) = (SELECT MAX(temp.cnt) AS maxi
                                FROM (SELECT hacker_id,
                                             COUNT(challenge_id) AS cnt
                                      FROM challenges
                                      GROUP BY hacker_id) temp )
    OR COUNT(c.challenge_id) IN ((SELECT temp.cnt
                                  FROM (SELECT hacker_id,
                                               COUNT(challenge_id) AS cnt
                                        FROM challenges
                                        GROUP BY hacker_id) temp
                                  GROUP BY temp.cnt
                                  HAVING COUNT(temp.cnt) = 1))
ORDER BY COUNT(c.challenge_id) DESC,
         h.hacker_id;
```

This query is giving correct answer

```sql
SELECT h.hacker_id,
       h.name,
       COUNT(c.challenge_id) AS c_count
FROM hackers h
     INNER JOIN challenges c ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
GROUP BY h.hacker_id,
         h.name
HAVING c_count = (SELECT MAX(temp.cnt) AS maxi
                  FROM (SELECT hacker_id,
                               COUNT(challenge_id) AS cnt
                        FROM challenges
                        GROUP BY hacker_id) temp )
    OR c_count IN ((SELECT temp.cnt
                    FROM (SELECT hacker_id,
                                 COUNT(challenge_id) AS cnt
                          FROM challenges
                          GROUP BY hacker_id) temp
                    GROUP BY temp.cnt
                    HAVING COUNT(temp.cnt) = 1))
ORDER BY COUNT(c.challenge_id) DESC,
         h.hacker_id;
```

using alias I  am getting correct answer.
Actually the only question is when I am using *count(c.challenge_id)* two times in having clause I am getting wrong answer and when I am using column alias *c_count* I am getting correct answer.

Comment: Please tag only a single RDBMS - not 3!

Comment: White space and line breaks are a *must* (they're magical things); they make your *very* difficult code easy to read. I suggest you get into the habit of using them as your queries are **very** difficult to understand. What are those random `*` characters in your SQL? They would could syntax errors.

Comment: Excess parenthesis in 1st query.

Comment: No I have added some more details of my specific doubt.